# Erro: R cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

Estou criando um projeto Android e estou enfrentando o seguinte erro na minha IDE.

```
package br.com.app;
import android.R;

public class MinhaApp extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
         setContentView (R.layout.main);
     }
}
```

Mas meu IDE dá o seguinte erro:

> R cannot be resolved

na linha

```
setContentView (R.layout.main);
```

Por quê isso está acontecendo? O arquivo `maix.xml` está na pasta `res/layout` corretamente.

Comment: Você fez `import android.R;`, se apagar esta linha já resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Dê `Clean` e depois `Build` no seu projeto.

Comment: Obrigado! Como essa classe é gerada dinamicamente durante a compilação, o import android.R deveria ser retirado.
Otimizando os imports pela IDE também resolveu.

Comment: Fazer isso é realmente muito chato, alguém deveria corrigir isso.

Answer (score 10):

Você importou o `R` 'errado' por engano. Troque a linha do `import` por:

```
import <pacote_do_projeto>.R
```

Por exemplo:

```
import br.com.app.R
```

Caso o pacote do projeto seja 'br.com.app'

Answer (score 5):

Isto acontece frequentemente quando você acabou de criar um projeto, o que me parece ser o seu caso, pelo que dá para ver do código.
Então é só relaxar e esperar um pouquinho.
Acontece que assim q você cria um novo projeto, vários processos estão rodando ao mesmo tempo (o compilador Java, os geradores do Android Development Tool, os outros plugins da IDE,...). Então às vezes demora um pouquinho para o ADT gerar a classe R.
Caso isso não aconteça é só seguir a resposta do @iTSangar.

Answer (score 5):

Esse é um erro comum que pode vir de várias origens diferentes:

- Erro em um dos XMLs (mesmo que não acuse);
- Não dar save antes do Clean/Build;
- Algum erro que esteja impedindo a geração automática desse arquivo;

Descobri uma solução até então "definitiva" aqui pro pessoal de onde trabalho.

EDIT.: Essa forma deve ser utilizada como último caso, se nenhuma das alternativas acima tiver funcionado:

Visto que naturalmente o Eclipse gera o arquivo e algo estava bloqueando esse procedimento, optei por fazê-lo de forma manual. Fui até o diretório (Agenda/gen/br/com/contatos/UI) (por exemplo), dentro da pasta do projeto, criei uma cópia do BuildConfig e editei seu nome para R. Em seguida, criei um novo projeto e copiei o código do R para a cópia. Por fim, no projeto da agenda de contatos, dei Save, Clean e Build All para que as configurações fossem atualizadas e os erros (gerados pela falta do mesmo) corrigidos. Desta forma, a nova classe R é adaptada de acordo com as requisições do código criado.

Não testei de todas as formas possíveis, porém, serviu para todos que indiquei. Não sei até que ponto é correto realizar os procedimentos dessa maneira, então peço que me deem um feedback caso não dê certo.

Comment: Recomendo a edição da sua resposta de forma a incluir esse recurso, para que futuros visitantes com a mesma dúvida possam resolvê-la.

Comment: Editado, Tiago.

Answer (score 4):

Isso pode ocorrer por vários motivos, porém os mais comuns são:

1. Projeto recém criado. Dê Clean e Build.
2. Ordem das classes no Java Build Path está incorreta ou prioridade errada. Deixe de preferência o seguinte: Android Dependencies, Android Private Libraries, as outras
3. Erro em algum xml (layout, drawable, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

**O que é o R**

Ao desenvolver aplicativos para android, os recursos implementados são definidos por um arquivo XML externo. Com isto é garantida a divisão entre camada de apresentação e a camada de aplicação, no fundo a separação da lógica da aparência.

É criado um ficheiro xml que armazena toda a informação contida na pasta 'res' do projecto.

O plugin ADT do Eclipse acede as referências de todos os recursos através da classe R, classe esta que é regerada sempre que um novo recurso é definido no projecto ou sempre que o projecto é reconstruido (rebuild).

Answer (score 1):

Sempre que acontece isso o clean resolve.
Porem já ouve vezes que nem assim resolveu.
Deletar a classe R.java, tive que fechar o eclipse e dar o clean, pois o eclipse recria.

Answer (score 1):

O import está errado. Se houver qualquer erro nos xmls, a classe R não é gerada. Leia os warnings e você vai saber o que é que está errado no seu projeto.

Answer (score -3):

As vezes somente fechar o projeto e abrir novamente resolve. Senão deletar, fechar e reabrir também resolve.