# Android Problemas com R

Tags: android-layout

Todos os Layouts do meu projeto não estão aceitando ser chamados no Android Studio. O que posso fazer?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54/erro-r-cannot-be-resolved) é semelhante à esta sua, talvez as respostas te ajudem em algo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu já tive esse problema uma vez, foi resolvido com:

*Build->Clean Project*

Se ainda não funcionar, tente:

*Tools->Android->"Sync Project with Gradle Files"*