# Android Studio não reconhece R. Alguma Solução?

Tags: android-studio

```
package com.example.consult.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber qual erro tenho nesta aplicação que aparece Cannot resolve symbol 'R' 
Acabei de instalar tudo: Android Studio, Java e até mesmo o Ubuntu. 
Obs: JRE 1.8_121 | Ubuntu 16.04 LTS | Android Studio 2.3

Comment: Já existe um tópico para isso. 
Veja se ajuda em seu problema
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54/erro-r-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: O problema daquele cara era outro, apesar do erro ser o mesmo

Comment: Ja tentou fazer rebuild do projeto?

Comment: Se já tentou Builder->Clean Project, verifique se algum layout tem erro.

Comment: acabei de criar o projeto, e tenho apenas um LinearLayout no xml. E apenas uma activity

Comment: Aquela resposta escolhida não é a unica resposta, veja esta por exemplo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70928/3635